# sort() by date throws exception. Which element failed?

Tags: python, sorting, exception

I am sorting a list of dictionaries by date with this code:

```
try:
    value["spotlight"].sort(key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x["start"], "%Y%m%d-%H%M"), reverse=True)
except:
    logger.info("sort exception")
    exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
    logger.info(exc_type)
    logger.info(exc_obj)
    logger.info(exc_tb.tb_lineno)
```

Since February began, I started seeing this exception:

```
<type 'exceptions.ValueError'> day is out of range for month
```

How can I tell which dictionary failed so I can debug?

PS - the list is about 500 elements long...

Comment: @BleedingFingers there's no traceback because he's catching the exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using a lambda for the key function, write a full function definition. Have this function catch the exception from `strptime` and raise its own exception with the date string identified.

Using the suggestion from the comments to add information to the existing exception object, with guidance from https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions

```
def start_key(x):
    d = None
    try:
        d = x["start"]
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(d, "%Y%m%d-%H%M")
    except Exception as e:
        if d:
            e.args += (d,)
        raise

value["spotlight"].sort(key=start_key, reverse=True)
```

Comment: It doesn't even have to raise its own exception, it can just add the info to the existing exception and then re-raise it.

Comment: All the syntax examples I'm finding are using my method above.  would you mind writing or pointing me to an example of what your suggesting

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly a 2013-02-29 or similar.

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime("20130132", "%Y%m%d")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 328, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 2
>>> 
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime("20130229", "%Y%m%d")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 447, in _strptime
    datetime_date(year, 1, 1).toordinal() + 1
ValueError: day is out of range for month
```